# When copyting to clipboard, it prompt "drag-mouse-1 is undefined"

Tags: emacs

I want to view  and copy all the binding after M-g  to the clipboard,
so, strike `M-g`, it then prompt

[image]

When copying  the clipboard,   it  failed and prompt:

`M-g <drag-mouse-1> is undefind`

How could solve the problem?

[image]

Additional notes:

no menus if emacs -Q , I git emacs.d from [purcell/emacs.d: An Emacs configuration bundle with batteries included](https://github.com/purcell/emacs.d)

Comment: Please provide a recipe, starting from `emacs -Q`. When I do `M-g` I see no such menu. It's not clear what you're doing.

Comment: Yes, no menus if `emacs -Q` , I git emacs.d from [purcell/emacs.d: An Emacs configuration bundle with batteries included](https://github.com/purcell/emacs.d) @Drew

Comment: Please put all such info in the question itself. Provide a recipe to reproduce your problem. Comments can be deleted at any time. Questions should stand alone.

Comment: it was append to the question. @Drew

Comment: That's not a recipe. That's just asking people to go see a bunch of code and debug things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe I have deciphered this question.

I suspect you have the `which-key` library enabled (or something very similar).  That is then displaying all the keys under the prefix binding `M-g`, after you have typed that key, while waiting for you to type the next key in the sequence.

You are then attempting to use the mouse to select the text of the displayed bindings in the which-key buffer; however Emacs is still waiting for you to finish the key sequence, so when you click the mouse button it tells you about the sequence `M-g <drag-mouse-1>`

You can't do what you're trying to do, because the `which-key` buffer does not persist after the key sequence has been completed.

What you should do is use the *standard* method of obtaining the same information, which is to type `C-h` after the prefix.

i.e. `M-g C-h`

That will then show you a `*Help*` buffer with all the bindings under that prefix, and you will be able to copy the text from that buffer.